# How to import React(jsx) file in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I have a problem when run *./bin/webpack-dev-server* in my Rails app I'm getting an error:

```
Failed to compile.

./app/javascript/packs/blob.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:1)

  3 | 
  4 | 
> 5 | <!DOCTYPE html>
    |  ^
```

I'm not sure what but I think something should be added to webpack.config.js

Comment: Hard to tell only from error, please provide more context (at least more or the code that the error comes from)

Comment: Sorry, I don't know which part of code should be relevant to this. It's simply throwing an error because javaScript identifier cannot contain '!'. It is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45351475/html-webpack-plugin-template-module-build-failed-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) but I don't know how to implement it

Comment: Obviously error comes from a file that contains `<!DOCTYPE html>`, you can search for that text, then look into how it got imported. Probably you do not have webpack loaders configured so that html is being fed into jsx upon import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your webpack configuration might be incorrect, it is trying to compile JavaScript from an html file, you need to specify an entry jsx file in your webpack config. I usually put all my jsx files into a `frontend` folder at project root and use the following webpack.config.js file at root

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: './frontend/ROOT FILE NAME.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app', 'assets', 'javascripts'),
    filename: 'bundle.      },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          presets: ['@babel/env', '@babel/react',],
          plugins: ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties']
        }
      },
    }]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"]
  }
};
```

Note that I have Babel with some extensions added, you may want to add more or remove some depending on JS syntax you’re using.

See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) on how to set up root file